# Group by and count on Spark Data frame all columns

Tags: scala, apache-spark, group-by, apache-spark-sql

I want to Perform Group by on each column of the data frame using Spark Sql. The Dataframe will have approx. 1000 columns.

I have tried Iterating over all the columns in the data frame and performed groupBy on each column. But the program is executing more than 1.5 hour

```
val df = sqlContext
      .read
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .options(Map( "table" -> "exp", "keyspace" -> "testdata"))
      .load()


val groupedData= channelDf.columns.map(c => channelDf.groupBy(c).count().take(10).toList)
println("Printing Dataset :"+ dataset)
```

If I have columns in the Dataframe For Example Name and Amount then the output should be like

GroupBy on column Name:

```
Name    Count
Jon     2
Ram     5
David   3
```

GroupBy on column Amount:

```
Amount  Count
1000    4
2525    3
3000    3
```

I want the group by result for each column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I can see a speed up here is to cache the `df` straight after reading it.

Unfortunately, each computation is independant, and you have to do them, there is no "work around".

Something like this can speed up a little bit, but not that much :

```
val df = sqlContext
      .read
      .format("org.apache.spark.sql.cassandra")
      .options(Map( "table" -> "exp", "keyspace" -> "testdata"))
      .load()
      .cache()
```

Comment: This helped.Thank you so much for your reply. Now the same code executed in 4min

Comment: @Rajashree I am glad to hear ! :) Do not hesitate to accept the answer :)

Comment: I have not earned the voting privilege. I will definitely accept the answer once I get it.

Comment: @Rajashree, you do not need vote privilege to accept, just click on the tick, thank you :)